# How to get symfony2 security BCRYPT encoder to work with php crypt() function

Tags: php, authentication, symfony, passwords, bcrypt

I am using bcrypt to hash my passwords and it seems that symfony2 authentication system is not production the same hash as php's native crypt function. Bellow is the salt that I am generating for my user password:

```
 $salt = '$2y$13$' . substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)),0,21) . '$';
 $this->setPassword('test',$salt);
```

In my security.yml file I am simply doing:

```
encoders:
    Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm:  bcrypt
        iterations: 13
```

Is there any reason why the two encoding methods would generate different hashes? The library I am using is ircmaxell/password-compat.

Comment: please provide the code you used for testing the crypt function. maybe it's the number of iterations?

Comment: Wich version of Symfony? Additionally, why are you setting the salt manually? And yet additionally, why are you generating the salt in such a horrific manner? Symfony will do this for you. Why are you trying to make it more difficult than it needs to be? Proof: [Symfony's Source Code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/BCryptPasswordEncoder.php#L48)

Comment: It is an intended behaviour, that you get a different hash-value every time, because you generate a different (random) salt for every calculation. This way an attacker cannot tell, whether two users have entered the same password. If you want to test the hashing, then just test if the verification fails/succeeds.

Answer (score 3):

Best way to use this within Symfony2 is to use get the encoder.

```
use \Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\User;

$user = new User();

$encoderFactory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
$encoder = $encoderFactory->getEncoder($user);

$salt = 'salt'; // this should be different for every user
$password = $encoder->encodePassword('password', $salt);

$user->setSalt($salt);
$user->setPassword($password);
```

If you are using FOSUserBundle, you should use:

```
use \Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\User;

$userManager = $this->get('fos_user_manager');

$password = 'password';
$user = new User();
$user->setPlainPassword($password);

$userManager->updateUser($user, true); // second argument tells user manager to flush
```

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing the source code for Symfony2.3 implementation of bcrypt, they use a function called hash_algorithm() and it seems to yield different results than crypt(). Both use $2y$ versions of bcrypt and I had set the cost for both algorithms to 13 ... however it is more consistent to do the following for setting passwords instead:

```
$user->setPassword(password_hash($user->getPassword(), PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 13)));
```

That line of code seemed to fix my problem. The best part is that I don't even have to generate my salt any more.